# Do I need separate google-services.json for firebase and Google APIs

Tags: android, google-signin

I am using firebase database in my app. I wish to add Google+ login using [Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) I don't want to use FirebaseUI for login feature. I have an existing google-services.json created from [firebase console](http://console.firebase.google.com). Do I need to create and add another google-services.json from [google developer](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In) console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the google-services.json that is supplied for your app in the Firebase console. If this is missing your Google+ sign-in parameter, you can supply it manually by calling a method or as a string resource.

I'm not sure about the parameter because I didn't do the google sign-in. Yet, I had a similar situation with running both Firebase and Google Analytics on the same app. There I used google-services.json from Firebase console and added missing GA tracked by calling newTracker `analytics.newTracker(GA_TRACKER_ID);`. I believe that with sign-in it's a similar procedure.

Comment: worked without adding GA tracked! Thanks! Any idea why do we have two different ways of creating google-services.json while the one from firebase console works everywhere?